# is object passed by reference or value by default

Tags: c++

When passing an object to a method or function is the object then passed by reference or value when the object is not initiated by the `new` keyword?

```
My_object a;

my_function(a);
```

Is the object then passed to the function as a reference or a value?

```
void my_function(My_object a){

}
```

Or do I need to add `&` ?

```
void my_function(My_object &a){

}
```

Comment: It's probably helpful to point out that the distinction between passing by value and passing by reference is a somewhat technical one and doesn't really mean, at a high level, that changes in the function are or aren't reflected in the object. For example, Java only passes by value, but if you pass a reference by value, the effect is the same as passing a value by reference. Since you typically pass references (by value, of course) in Java, it seems like pass by reference. This is probably why you think it matters whether the object was created with `new` even though it makes no difference.

Comment: research topics - formal parameter, actual parameter

Answer (score 2):

The way an object is passed depends on the function's parameters and not on the way the object was created.

`My_object a` means it's passed by value.

For passing by reference you need to use `My_object& a`.  If you do not intend to change the object, you may prefer `const My_object& a`. This will avoid accidental overwrite.

Comment: Or if it's an input argument, better use `const My_object& a`

Comment: ok.. so if I use `const` then I can't change the object (override with a new instance of the same object) but I can still make changes to the object.. like changing some properties etc?

Comment: @clarkk `const` mainly to avoid mistakes. For performance, by value and by reference could make a difference.  But beyond, you'd better trust your compiler's optimizer ;-)

Comment: @clarkk Depends on the class. If you really need to, you can use `mutable` keyword to allow some fields of the objects to be updated, either directly or by a `const` method of that class. This only required rarely for complex objects that have a cache inside or something similar.

Unless you use `mutable` in that class, the compiler prevents you from modifying that object passed by const reference. Often a good idea because prevents a class of bugs, e.g. if you accidentally type `if(a.field=0)` it just won’t compile if `a` is a const reference.